# Best way to check the mobile device resolution height

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile, resolution, nicescroll

I have form page in `HTML5`.
The page is too much big so I added a scroll: [jquery.nicescroll](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/)

I wrapped the form with `<div>` and set a iPhone 4 `height:480px` and run the `niceScroll` constructor function.

```
<div id = "scroller"> 
<form>
..
...
......
</form>
</div>

<script>
$('#scroller').niceScroll(); 
</script>
```

It works fine, but the issue is that I should give to each device his own **height : (height-40px)** so it will look nice on device.
For example: for Iphone4 height:480px, for iPhone5: 568px,Samsung S2 533 etc.

What is the best way to check the height value of device so I can use it after that?
Now I can check the device company with `userAgent`:

```
navigator.userAgent.indexOf("iPhone")
```

But I need to know exactly the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use this:

```
 $(window).height();
```

Read [here](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

Comment: strange, **Samsung S2** resolution is 320X533 and `$(window).height()` show 508

Comment: May be but this is only way I used for iphone android and other mobiles.

Answer (score 1):

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Please set the multipal device height in this code.